# Verify that a document matches a URL

Tags: import, web-access, internet, url

Writing:

```
Quiet[Length[Import["http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf"]]]
```

I get:

> 2

while writing:

```
Quiet[Length[Import["http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sampl.pdf"]]]
```

I get:

> 0

This is my crude method to check if a URL matches a document or not. Is there a more efficient method? Thank you!

Comment: You can do it faster by importing the `"String"` import format and comparing that to the document you have

Comment: Use the second arg to `Import`